# Is there a way to add an id to a label and replace label textusing javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm currentyl using this script but seems like its not working properly

```
$("label[for='fe4781']").get(0).id = "privacypolicytext"; // add id to label

window.onload = function () {
    var dataPrivacy = document.getElementById('privacypolicytext'); //div ID of privacy policy text

    dataPrivacy.innerHTML = 'Lorem ipsum text <a data-targettype="webpage" href="https://www.sample.com">Lorem ipsum</a>.' <span class="required">*</span> ;
};
```

Field names are as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privacyPolicy" id="fe4781">
<label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label" for="fe4781">Text to replace</label>
```

Looking for a wat to implement the above script. to add an id to label field and replace the label text

Comment: Other than the closing `'` being in the wrong place, your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/gsh6wmek/

Comment: *seems like its not working* - the browser console tells you why: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'class'`

Comment: Do you want to use native JS _or_ jQuery - you have a mix of the two at the moment.

Comment: @Andy Im looking for a way to implement the approach above using native JS.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to select/cache the label element once. You can then add the new `id`, and the new HTML to that cached element.

To make sure the DOM is loaded before the script runs either have you `<script>` in the `<head>` and add [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer), or move the `<script>` to just before the `</body`> closing tag.

```js
const id = 'privacypolicytext';
const html = 'Lorem ipsum text <a data-targettype="webpage" href="https://www.sample.com">Lorem ipsum</a>.<span class="required">*</span>';

const label = document.querySelector('label[for="fe4781"]');

label.id = id;
label.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="privacyPolicy" id="fe4781">
<label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label" for="fe4781">Text to replace</label>
```